Process 'command 'C:\Users\mahes\dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1
lib/controller/auth_controller.dart:44:36: Error: Required named parameter 'altitudeAccuracy' must be provided.
Position _pickPosition = Position(longitude: 0, latitude: 0, timestamp: DateTime.now(), accuracy: 1, altitude: 1, heading: 1, speed: 1, speedAccuracy: 1);
^
/C:/Users/mahes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/geolocator_platform_interface-4.2.2/lib/src/models/position.dart:9:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const Position({
^^^^^^^^
lib/controller/auth_controller.dart:602:29: Error: Required named parameter 'altitudeAccuracy' must be provided.
_pickPosition = Position(
^
/C:/Users/mahes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/geolocator_platform_interface-4.2.2/lib/src/models/position.dart:9:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const Position({
^^^^^^^^
lib/view/screens/html/html_viewer_screen.dart:42:40: Error: 'RenderContext' isn't a type.
onLinkTap: (String? url, RenderContext context, Map<String, String> attributes, element) {
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
lib/view/screens/html/html_viewer_screen.dart:42:26: Error: The argument type 'void Function(String?, invalid-type, Map<String, String>, dynamic)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(String?, Map<String, String>, Element?)?'.

'Map' is from 'dart:core'.
'Element' is from 'package:html/dom.dart' ('/C:/Users/mahes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/html-0.15.4/lib/dom.dart').
onLinkTap: (String? url, RenderContext context, Map<String, String> attributes, element) {
^
/C:/Users/mahes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/country_code_picker-2.0.2/lib/country_code_picker.dart:203:73: Error: The getter 'button' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/Users/mahes/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'button'.
widget.textStyle ?? Theme.of(context).textTheme.button,
^^^^^^
/C:/Users/mahes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pin_code_fields-7.4.0/lib/src/pin_code_fields.dart:669:56: Error: The getter 'button' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/Users/mahes/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'button'.
color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button!.color,
^^^^^^
/C:/Users/mahes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pin_code_fields-7.4.0/lib/src/pin_code_fields.dart:679:60: Error: The getter 'button' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/Users/mahes/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'button'.
color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button!.color,
^^^^^^
/C:/Users/mahes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pin_code_fields-7.4.0/lib/src/pin_code_fields.dart:696:58: Error: The getter 'button' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/Users/mahes/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'button'.
color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button!.color),
^^^^^^
/C:/Users/mahes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/pin_code_fields-7.4.0/lib/src/pin_code_fields.dart:705:60: Error: The getter 'button' isn't defined for the class 'TextTheme'.
'TextTheme' is from 'package:flutter/src/material/text_theme.dart' ('/C:/Users/mahes/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/text_theme.dart').
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing getter, or defining a getter or field named 'button'.
color: Theme.of(context).textTheme.button!.color,
^^^^^^
/C:/Users/mahes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/screenshot-2.3.0/lib/screenshot.dart:164:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'size'.
size: logicalSize,
^^^^
/C:/Users/mahes/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:28:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const ViewConfiguration({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
/C:/Users/mahes/AppData/Local/Pub/Cache/hosted/pub.dev/flutter_star_prnt-2.4.1/lib/src/print_commands.dart:205:9: Error: No named parameter with the name 'size'.
size: logicalSize,
^^^^
/C:/Users/mahes/dev/flutter/packages/flutter/lib/src/rendering/view.dart:28:9: Context: Found this candidate, but the arguments don't match.
const ViewConfiguration({
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
Target kernel_snapshot failed: Exception

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

Where:
Script 'C:\Users\mahes\dev\flutter\packages\flutter_tools\gradle\src\main\groovy\flutter.groovy' line: 1629

What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileFlutterBuildDebug'.



Process 'command 'C:\Users\mahes\dev\flutter\bin\flutter.bat'' finished with non-zero exit value 1


Try:


Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 7m 40s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
i need run flutter run and also same issue in all the flutter app same only

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Ok I will provide

what kind`s of code need plz telme
